# Multisample framebuffer only incomplete with renderbuffer

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, opengl-3, opengl-4

I am setting up a multisampled framebuffer with 4 color attachments and 1 depth stencil attachment.  It currently is incomplete with GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE.  If I dont attach the renderbuffer it works perfectly.  Debug output isnt printing anything, and glGetError() isnt showing any problems.

```
GLint samples;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_SAMPLES, &samples);

const GLuint target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE;
const GLenum format[TEXTURES_PER_FBO] = {
    GL_RGBA32F, GL_RGB32F, GL_RGB32F, GL_R8UI   // TODO tune these
};

// create render textures
glGenTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, textures);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEXTURES; i++) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    glBindTexture(target, textures[i]);
    const int index = i % TEXTURES_PER_FBO;
    glTexStorage2DMultisample(target, samples, format[index], width, height, false);
}

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, samples, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);

// create first framebuffer with depth attachment
glGenFramebuffers(NUM_FBOS, fbos);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbos[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURES_PER_FBO; i++) {
    const GLenum index = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i;
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, index, target, textures[i], 0);
}
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

'status' is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE

I have tested it on both a gtx 980 and 480 on windows.  I dont have access to others at the moment, but I'll try to get some if this isnt resolved.
If you need more code for context, it can be found [here](https://github.com/jkevin1/Trace) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `GL_TRUE` for the *fixedsamplelocations* (last) argument of `glTexStorage2DMultisample()` if you also have renderbuffer attachements. Otherwise you'll get exactly the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE` error you observe.

From the list of possible `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` results in the spec (e.g. page 311 of the OpenGL 4.5 spec, section "9.4.2 Whole Framebuffer Completeness"):

> The value of TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS is the same for all attached textures; and, if the attached images are a mix of renderbuffers and textures, the value of TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS must be TRUE for all attached textures. {FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE}

So you need to change the call to this to get a valid FBO configuration:

```
glTexStorage2DMultisample(target, samples, format[index], width, height, GL_TRUE);
```